# Retrieving data from parse in NSMutable array and then get the data from the cells where the button has been tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So this is how I'm retrieving all the data and then added a custom button this way :

```
import UIKit

class userListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery?.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, erroe) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.data.addObject(object)



                        }




                    }

                }



            }


           self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return data.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("users", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userListTableViewCell

    let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    // Usernames and gender..

    myCell.fullName.text = userData.objectForKey("fullName") as! String!
    myCell.genderLabel.text = userData.objectForKey("gender") as! String!

    // Profile pictures..

    let profilePics = userData.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
    profilePics.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.dp.image = downloadedImage
        }

    }

    myCell.followButtton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)

    myCell.followButtton.addTarget(self, action: "followButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



    return myCell
}

// IBActions..


func followButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    if indexPath != nil {



        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as? userListTableViewCell {
          cell.followButtton.setTitle("unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            var followers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
                followers["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
                followers["user"] = //*********************** here i want to save the objectId of the user being tapped on. want to get the NSMutableArray index from the indexPath

        }

      println(indexPath!)


    }
}
```

my problem is there where you see `************************`. now like in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I've used this to show the data :

```
  let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
```

same like this i want to do it in `func followButton(sender:AnyObject)`.

Comment: It's wrong to call cellForRowAtIndexPath when the button is tapped.  But I don't understand the question, why not just do what you've suggested: get the index path for the button, then the object corresponding to that index path with `self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)` ?

Comment: `self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row` it worked.. But how calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a bad idea? How else we can  change the title of the button when tapped?? @danh

Comment: That method is to be called by the table view when it determines a row must be displayed.  What you want to do is change your model (change the object in self.data[indexPath.row]) and then reload that row.  The table will call cellForRowAtIndexPath for you.  There, you'll examine the object at self.data[indexPath.row] and change the button title based on the state of the object (we call that the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)` this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the for loop, you should do that only once at the end of the for loop when all the data is loaded.